# how to loop the array and set new array with old array ? using hooks useState with the type Date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i want to add arrays in one array ,
for example :
i have list of Object in array like

`const arr=[{a ,b},{c,d},{e,f}]`

i want to loop in `arr` and return on array
`[a ,b ,c ,d ,e ,f]`

how can i do it , using `useState` hook with the type Date

Comment: Your objects are not valid javascript so it is difficult to know what you are trying to extract into the result array. Clarify this for accurate answers. Also you give no context for how this relates to react, useState or Date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
const arr=[{'a':'b'},{'c':'d'},{'e':'f'}]
const result = arr.map(e => Object.entries(e).flat()).flat()
console.log(result)
```